# Converting a NSAttributedString into a NSString using Swift

Tags: swift, string, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a `NSMutableAttributedString` and want to convert it back into a simple `String`.

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello w0rld")
```

How can I get just the `String` out of a `NSMutableAttributedString` the easiest?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Use the `string` property on `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello, world!")
var s = attributedString.string
```

Comment: @Julian: Well, yes, an `NSString` doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: Right, but the NSAttributedString does. I was hoping that the attributes would be rendered along with the string. You  know what I mean? otherwise these get lost.

Comment: @Julian: In that case, you wouldn't bother converting to `NSString`.

Comment: There are things are simpler with regular strings like adjusting the text to fit a frame, or replacing the text of label. Additionally, it is less expensive to use strings if you are manipulating the text frequently. So this is why I would bother converting it.

Comment: @JulianB. if you want a normal string with attributes conserved, use String(yourAttributedString)

Comment: The `string` property returns a `String` object, not an `NSString` object.

Answer (score 6):

If you strictly want an `NSString`, not a `String` use the following:

```
let s = attributedString.string as NSString
```

Comment: This answer has already given by `mipadi`. OP asked for `NSString` because question is old and at that time `Swift` had `NSString` not `String`. So nowadays probably nobody would like to get `NSString` from `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: @TheTiger There are still cases where you might specifically want an `NSString` instead of a `String`. In particular, if you need to use an `NSRange` from the string. `NSRange` is not compatible with `Range`.

Comment: Still in 2018 it is very basic to convert `String` into `NSString`.

Comment: Sure, it is basic, but some people don't know and if you Google this is the first answer that comes up, so for some people this might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep the atributted string simply use `yourLabel.attributedText = atributedTtext`